# Images does not align as expected

Tags: php, html, css

All of my images are placed in order, but in the 3rd row my image does not aligned as the images above. I cannot figure out what the problem is. Actually it was working fine until the admin uploaded a image image with a blank filed, but that was sorted out and when again the images were upload the problem began to rise. Here is the link for my problem.

http://hurdec.org.np/about_us.php

```
                <?php 

            $about = sliding_image();
            while($about_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($about)){ 
        ?> 
        <div class="row">

            <div class="span3">

                <div class="team-member">

                    <div class="team-member-preview"> 

                        <img src="images/<?php echo $about_fetch["image_name"];?>" alt="">

                        <div class="team-member-hover">

                            <div class="social-media fixed">
                                <a class="youtube-icon social-icon" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="pinterest-icon social-icon" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="facebook-icon social-icon" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="twitter-icon social-icon" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div><!-- end .social-media -->

                        </div><!-- end .team-member-hover -->

                    </div><!-- end .team-member-preview -->

                    <h5><?php echo $about_fetch["name"];?></h5>
                    <p class="mute"><?php echo $about_fetch["qualification"];?></p>

                    <div class="adjust_about">
                     <h5> Areas of Expertise </h5>
                     <ul>

                     <li><?php echo $about_fetch["area_of_expertise"];?> </li> 

                     </ul>


                    </div>


                </div><!-- end .team-member -->

            </div><!-- end .span3 -->

                <?php
            }
                  ?>
 </div>         
         </div>  

     </div>
                 <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">

                <div class="divider single-dotted"></div>

            </div><!-- end .span12 -->
        </div><!-- end .row -->
```

Comment: You've got too many `.row` divs around. You should rename each persons 'block' as something like `.box` instead, and then make them `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

It's because Yadap has a shorter bio than the others.  Add a

```
<br clear="left" />
```

after every 4th bio.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove your

```
<div class="row">
```

from the loop. You should only define this once, and then append the span3 elements inside it.
Like so:

```
<div class="row">
<?php 
    $about = sliding_image();
    while($about_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($about)){ 
?>    
<div class="span3">
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Also, the team-member class should have a fixed height as your code is now. When one of them is shorter than the other, you get the kind of trouble you are having right now.

What you also could do is add 4 elements to a row, then close it and open a new row-tag for the next four elements.

Comment: I tried as you said and, it did not appear right, but could sort few problems. could you have a look again. i need to deliver it by today so.